# cache_on method doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, pdo

I would like to cache some sql queries on my website. I saw that CodeIgniter proposed a  [Database Caching Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html).

But when I call the caching method like `$this->db->cache_on();` my script return this error :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::cache_on()**

I think that I have configured correctly my database.php config file :

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = 'application/cache';
```

Maybe it's my PDO's version is too old? Which version do I need?

Answer (score 1):

The manual says "Enable the caching feature, either globally by setting the preference in your application/config/database.php file, **or** manually as described below."

So doing both `$this->db->cache_on();` **and** `$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;`
 seems redundant. The first one is for using globally, the second one is for a specific part of your code.

What's your MySQL version? You can find it using `phpinfo();` You will need 4.1+.

If you want to see if caching works, use one or the other method, check file permissions on your caching directory, run some queries and see if CI stored files in the directory.